# Java - Google App engine - Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded

Tags: java, google-app-engine

the requests suddenly stopped and I don't know why this happen.
I am using java11.

{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry", "statusDetails":"client_disconnected_before_any_response"}

[image]

this my app engine configs

```
<precompilation-enabled>false</precompilation-enabled>
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe> 

<instance-class>F4</instance-class>
<automatic-scaling>
    <max-concurrent-requests>50</max-concurrent-requests>
    <max-pending-latency>8s</max-pending-latency> 
    <min-pending-latency>4s</min-pending-latency> 
    <min-instances>1</min-instances> 
    <min-idle-instances>1</min-idle-instances>
</automatic-scaling>
```

Answer (score 1):

Error you're getting means as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#statusdetail_http_failure_messages) that the client disconnected before load balancer could reply:

> client_disconnected_before_any_response - The connection to the client
> was broken before the load balancer sent any response.

And the Error code 123 is a  Deadline Exceeded Error

> HARD_REQUEST_TIME_LIMIT- Request exceeded a deadline, causing the
> instance to shut down

Here are some known issues that cause this issue:

- High latency, this means that your startup code for instances may take too long, what is recommended in this case is to set a “min_idle_instances”  just remember that this might cause an increase in your billing.
- Running multiple requests in parallel, this can cause a thread deadlock and result in timeouts; in this case it is recommend to use load balancers.

As also mentioned in this stackoverflow [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58204901/18265638) by LundinCast

> - You've most likely set your App Engine service scaling element to "autoscaling" (or didn't define it, autoscaling being the default
>   value) in the app.yaml file.
> - Instances in autoscaling have a deadline of 10min, as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling). You'll need to re-deploy your service with an updated
>   app.yaml file setting the scaling element to "manual scaling" or
>   "basic scaling" to allow your tasks to run to up to 24h.

You might also check this similar cases for more information

[how to solve "Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. (Error code 123)" in google api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913255/how-to-solve-process-terminated-because-the-request-deadline-was-exceeded-err)

[Google App Engine: Intermittent Issue: Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. (Error code 123)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65609509/googel-app-engine-intermittent-issue-process-terminated-because-the-request-de)